# List width and height of all images in a folder from Linux command line

Tags: linux, image, command-line, dimension

I want to see the image dimensions of all the jpg images together in a list through a command line in Linux. Following code works for only one image.

```
    identify -format "%wx%h" xxxx.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```sh
 xargs  identify -format "%wx%h\n" < <(ls -tr1)
```

or

```sh
ls -1 | xargs -L1 identify -format "%wx%h\n"
```

Comment: Both work but the second one was useful because it lists the dimensions in the same sequence as the image files in the folder.

Comment: Why not simply do someting like `identify -format "%f: %wx%h\n" path/to/images/*.jpg`?

Answer (score 2):

if you have files with spaces in their names, you can use this command, which specify `'\n'` as delimiter.

```sh
ls *.jpg | xargs -d '\n' -L1 identify -format "%wx%h\n"
```

and if you want to have a mapping of filenames to dimensions you can use `%f` in your pattern:

```sh
ls *.jpg | xargs -d '\n' -L1 identify -format "%f: %wx%h\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I have with the other answers is that you have to be in the same directory as the images.

So a solution that avoids this chains xargs together:

```
ls folder | xargs -I % echo "path_to_folder/%" | xargs identify -quiet -ping -format '%w %h\n'
```

Note this only works for one folder not multiple subfolders.